# Microsoft Graph api cannot send invitation to share document

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

My goal is to share a document/file with another user.

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to do it.

Error I have:

> Client error: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/operations.xlsx:/invite resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The request is malformed or incorrect. Expected array for value of property: Collection(microsoft.graph.driveRecipient)","innerError":{"date":"2022-03-08T10:48:30","request-id":"xxx-xxxx-xxxxx","client-request-id":"xxx-xxxx-xxxxx"}}}

Find below my code:

operations.xlsx is the file I am trying to share.

```
public function send(){

  $viewData = $this->loadViewData();
  $graphs = $this->getGraph();

  $body = array(

  "requireSignIn"=> true,
  "sendInvitation" => true ,
  "roles" => "[write | read]",
  "recipients"=>array(
     "email"=> "person@email.com" 
    ),
  "message"=> "Here is the file."
  );

  $graphs->createRequest("post", "/me/drive/root:/operations.xlsx:/invite")
         ->attachBody($body)
         ->execute();

  return response()->json($graphs);

}
```

I am using Laravel for the project.

Comment: Why are you sending parameters that the documentation you referred to doesn't even list for this request (type, scope)? Why are you arbitrarily changing the spelling of the parameter names shown there, regarding upper- and lowercase letters? (`requireSignIn` and `sendInvitation` in the docs, `RequireSignIn` and `SendInvitation` in your code.)

Comment: Sorry I was also trying the createLink function [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I have mixed them both. but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: `recipients` is an _array_ of objects in their example request, yours is a simple array.

Comment: You are right I had to add [] in recipients. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function sended(){

$viewData = $this->loadViewData();
$graphs = $this->getGraph();

$body = array(


"requireSignIn"=> true,
"sendInvitation" => true ,
"roles" => ["read"],
"recipients"=>array([
"email"=> "person@email.com"
]),
"message"=> "Here is the file."
);

$graphs->createRequest("post", "/me/drive/root:/operations.xlsx:/invite")
->attachBody($body)
->execute();

return response()->json($graphs);
}
```